# Generate ios/android data entry form dynamically from XSD using codename one

Tags: java, mobile, xsd, codenameone

As I m new in mobile application development so I have no idea how to build mobile application specifically like below.

I need one demo application from which I can generate dynamic form using XSD schema file using 
codename one api which can be compatible with ios and android.

I m also want to know whether codename one api would be compatible for all mobile devices ?
like one code will be build different build file which will be compatible with iphone 4/5/5s , Samsung android , nexus , apple Ipad etc..

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One is compatible to all these devices. However, it doesn't support generating UI's from XSD's, you need to actually design the UI using a GUI builder or handcode it. There are plenty of docs guides & video links in the site http://www.codenameone.com/

Comment: Hi..Thanks for response..is there any way that I can parse xsd file using codename one ?

Comment: Actually what I m looking for is..form added in codename one will be coming dynamically, as i have one xsd file which contains elements with relevant type. I will parsing that xsd file and dynamically generated input elements for form..and save that form values in one xml file. so everytime my form UI will be different.

Comment: You can use the XMLParser class to parse XML files then generate the UI based on that.